# Microsoft Azure directory with multi-tenant application pattern

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, django-allauth

I've been searching this for a while now. Does anybody here know how to handle the below case.

I have a SaaS app which requires SSO using Azure directory. I'm able to do it with `django-allauth`. Now, I need to restrict this to tenants(customers) who have a subscription with us.

To do this, I'm thinking, if I can get the tenantId from Azure directory then I can do a database lookup to see if the customer has a subscription with us. So, does anybody here know how can I accomplish that?

[Here is a reference from MS](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-handle-multiple-issuer-values) which is not that clear on the `how to get tenantId part`.

The code from MS for `.net` for doing what I want to do with `django-allauth`: [MS .NET sample app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to the above problem. Whenever the authentication is successful, we get an `access token` which is a `Json Web Token`.

Now, if you decode that `JWT`, you'll get certain `claims` that come with it. One of the `claims` by the key `tid` is the `tenantId`.

So, in terms of a solution, what I did was this:

- Overrode the `DefaultSocialAccountAdapter`
- Inside that I overrode the `pre_social_login` and decoded the `access token` to get the `tenantId`.
- Now, all I needed was a list of `tenantId`'s to verify against. I'm taking that from the user who has admin access for that company.

Hope this helps someone. I'll  be happy to add or clarify the approach more, if needed.